# Linear transformation of SD and mean

Tags: data-transformation, mean, standard-deviation, linear

If one uses the following: $$(5-x)/5 = y $$
For 5 values (n=5)

And I have the mean of y. To get the mean of x I understand that I just move it around so I have:
$$\bar x = 5 - (5 \times \bar y)$$

If I also have the SD of mean y; do I just get the mean of x by multiplying it by 5?

Example:
n = 5,
mean y = 0.8,
SD y = 0.09

so will mean x = 1, and SD x = 0.45?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your notation @SPro

Comment: does this help? (edited above)

Comment: @Taylor (first time using this sorry)

Comment: It's all good. Still a little confused though--should the first equation involve $\bar{x}$ or $x_i$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$?

Comment: The first equation is xi correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two rules that you might find useful. If you have a random variable $W$, and a constant $c$, then

1. $\operatorname{Var}(cW) = c^2 \operatorname{Var}(W)$
2. $\operatorname{Var}(W + c) = \operatorname{Var}(W)$

If $(5-X_i)/5 = Y_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,5$, then summing both sides over $i$ gives you what you have written: 
$$
\bar{X} = 5 - 5  \bar{Y}.
$$
So take the variance of both sides of that. You should get, using the two rules above, that 
$$
\operatorname{Var}(\bar{X}) = 25 \operatorname{Var}(\bar{Y}).
$$
And if you take the square root of both sides of this, you should get 
$$
\operatorname{SD}(\bar{X}) = 5 \operatorname{SD}(\bar{Y}).
$$